# google-endpoints cross client authentication

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to use cross client authentication with google-endpoins. In my android client I'm successfully getting the authorization token for my server using:

```
String plusLogin = Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
String mScopes = "oauth2:" + plusLogin;

String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, Constants.accountName, mScopes);
```

then i'm accessing the desired endpoint in an AsyncTask task and passing this token to the server. Now... i have this token on the server side but I do not know what i have to do to decode the user information from int. Basically i'm interested to get the user id and the user email on the server side.

It is true that i'm new to this but I'm struggling for more then 2 weeks.
The Google documentation on this it is only pointing in the direction that you have to follow but with no working examples that you can use as a model to start from. 
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot decode any user information from the tokens provided by the Google API server to your App, as these tokens are signed tokens which is sent by the Google API server to your application. It is a onetime token sent by the Google API Server to your application and then your application sending this  to your server to get the refresh token from the Google Server.All these tokens are cryptographically signed JWT (Jason Web token) which is signed by Google, si you cannot decode those tokens.

Also, the docs you provided is for Google+ API and they have some sample code for how to implement the feature of onetime code in your project [1].

[1] https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/

Comment: So the next steps for the flow would be: 1. Exchange this token for an refresh token. 2.Access the https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me api and get the user details paked in a json format. I'm only finding examples on how to do this for android, javascript but not pure java on the server side. Can anyone help?